# Nested routing is not working in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying **react router v6**. As per [react training blog](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/), I have created object of routing and passed to `useRoutes()`:

```
function SomeOtherElement() {
  return <h1>add user</h1>;
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    element: <DashboardLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'account', element: <AccountView /> },
      {
        path: 'users', element: <UserListView />, 
        children: [
          { path: 'add', element: <SomeOtherElement /> }
        ]
      },
      { path: 'dashboard', element: <DashboardView /> },
      { path: 'products', element: <ProductListView /> },
      { path: 'settings', element: <SettingsView /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
    ]
  }];

const routing = useRoutes(routes);
```

But the nested routing is not working. As you can see in above object, I want to create URL and render the UI for user "**add**" functionality.

URL in the browser is getting updated correctly to **http://localhost:3000/app/users/add** but UI is not updating.

Answer (score 58):

The default behavior of React Router fails to render multiple child routes with single Outlet. For example - When there is requirement to have a single Header in all the pages and replace the common content (Single Outlet) based on Route.

The trick here is to not provide any **element** attribute for parent but to provide this component as a child route with the help of **[Index](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#index-routes)** attribute.

Index helps us to have a default component for a parent route if the child routes doesn't match any of the child routes.

The code snippet for this would be similar to the one provided by Samira.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      <Route path="" element={<Home />}></Route>
      <Route path="child1"> //no element attribute here
        <Route index={true} element={<Child1 />}></Route>
        <Route path="grandChild1" element={<GrandChild1 />}></Route>
        <Route path="grandChild2" element={<GrandChild2 />}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Would this be considered an exploit? And does this work to even deeper hierarchies?

Comment: I don't think it should be considered exploit. And about the hierarchies, I have personally not tried on deeper levels, but yes if we have got the concepts correct, then it should work.

Comment: The `index={true}` fixed my issue (for anyone else who might stumble here with the same issue as me)

Comment: It would have been helpful to post what this looks like inside `useRoutes([])` as objects in the array, and not markup. The question originally posed it like that. It is not difficult to translate but would speed it up for new people not understanding the difference between descendent and nested routes. (Tried to post it, but too ugly and unreadable in a comment)

Comment: Thank you, this solves the issue. Was using nextjs, switched to base react for a project and now I remember that I seldom hated the router.

Answer (score 28):

As explained [here](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#nested-routes-and-layouts), you need to use an `<Outlet />` element as a placeholder for child i.e. nested routes.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

// ... 

const routes = [
  {
    path: "app",
    element: (
      <>
        <DashboardLayout />
        <Outlet />
      </>
    ),
    children: [
      { path: "account", element: <AccountView /> },
      {
        path: "users",
        element: (
          <>
            <UserListView />
            <Outlet />
          </>
        ),
        children: [{ path: "add", element: <SomeOtherElement /> }],
      },
      { path: "dashboard", element: <DashboardView /> },
    ],
  },
];
```

Or you may want to have `Outlet` inside your parent components:

```
export default function DashboardLayout() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>I am Dashboard Layout</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 13):

It is a helpful example for me because I wanted to use nested Route but I didn't want to use Outlet so I found it :

pay attention you can make a dynamic route with `path=":teamId"`

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/">
            <Route index={true} element={<Home />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/teams">
            <Route index={true} element={<ParentTeam />} />
            <Route index={false} path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
            <Route index={false} path="new" element={<NewTeamForm />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
```

[link to codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-night-dybdu?file=/src/teams/index.js)

Comment: What actually the index prop does?

Comment: the index determines the main page in a specific route

Comment: so the path of ParentTeam is "/teams"

Comment: Thanks, @Samira !

Comment: Thanks @Samira.  Saved me man....  No need to explicitly put index except if it IS the index.  Again thanks....

Comment: You're welcome @MarkaA. I put the index in each route to have a better understanding.

Comment: At least in react-router-dom v6.9.0, the index cannot be set.

Answer (score 3):

For the `useRoutes` hook the syntax looks like this:

```
const items = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: "/logout",
    element: <Logout />,
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    element:  <RequireAuth element={<Welcome />} />,
  },
  {
    path: "/inbox",
    element:  <RequireAuth element={<Inbox />} />
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element:  <RequireAuth element={<Dashboard />} />
      },
      {
        path: "setup",
        element:  <RequireAuth element={<DashboardSetup/>} />
      },
    ]
  },


]

export default function MainContent() {
  const router = useRoutes(items);
  return router

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The index entry resolves fine, but the next child causes the page not to render and, in my case, throws the error: 'GET http://localhost:3000/characters/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)' when trying to load 'http://localhost:3000/characters/new'

Answer (score 0):

When setting path in childerns array you should allow using api history in dev server config:

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
```

here is a link to docs:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback

and here is tutorial

https://youtu.be/acAH2_YT6bs?list=PL6DxKON1uLOHyPVa0XhcqcW2RhDytDpAI&t=4891