# React Router Dom V6 Nested Route Attributes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

On the React Router Dom v5 I had a working code where I could use the nested elements. V5 Code was:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" />
        {user && (
          <>
            <Route path="/movies">
              <Home type="movie" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/series">
              <Home type="series" />
            </Route>
          </>
        )}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

... Now when I am trying to move to V6 version I cant access the content of nested page. These two nested routes showing the content based on "type" attribute, but in v6 I dont get any content at all. What I see, is only the home page. When I am trying to navigate through the navbar, only link is changing, but I cant access the content of the type element.

My current v6 code:

App.jsx:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} >
          <Route path="/movies" element={<Home type='movies'/>} />
          <Route path="/series" element={<Home type='series'/>} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Home.jsx:

```
const Home = ({type}) => {
      return (
        <div className='home'>
            <Navbar />
            <Featured type={type} />
            <List />
            <List />
            <List />
            <List />
            <Outlet />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Can someone, please help me to understand what I am doing wrong and why react router does not load the content of the component?

Comment: not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64291991/nested-routing-is-not-working-in-react-router-v6

Comment: It seems like you are nesting two `<Outlet />` in the parent `<Route />` and in child. `<Outlet />` is supposed to be one and outlet renders child nested components

Comment: Also, when I am trying to delete element from the parent route, the content starts showing up, but when navigating, its not switching the links, but adding one on another ex. "/series/movies".  
I already tried to add <Outlet /> only on children elements, but didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell the RRDv6 code isn't an accurate conversion. The v6 version is recursively rendering the `Home` component. The nested routes shouldn't also be using absolute paths.

Suggestions

1. Remove the `Home` component and `Outlet` from `Home` and just render the two nested routes. If the intent is to render a `Home` component without any type then use an index route.

   ```
   const Home = ({ type }) => {
     return (
       <div className='home'>
         <Navbar />
         <Featured type={type} />
         <List />
         <List />
         <List />
         <List />
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <Route path="/">
     <Route index element={<Home />} />
     <Route path="movies" element={<Home type='movies' />} />
     <Route path="series" element={<Home type='series' />} />
   </Route>
   ```
2. Flatten all the routes and remove the `Outlet` from `Home`, which is basically the same as above but now uses absolute paths.

   ```
   const Home = ({ type }) => {
     return (
       <div className='home'>
         <Navbar />
         <Featured type={type} />
         <List />
         <List />
         <List />
         <List />
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="/movies" element={<Home type='movies' />} />
   <Route path="/series" element={<Home type='series' />} />
   ```
3. Define a single route and use the `path` to your advantage. In other words, declare a path where the `type` is a route path param, and check the `type` from the params in the `Home` component.

   ```
   const Home = () => {
     const { type } = useParams();
     return (
       <div className='home'>
         <Navbar />
         <Featured type={type} />
         <List />
         <List />
         <List />
         <List />
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="/:type" element={<Home />} />
   ```

Comment: Thank you. Now at least I can see the content of /movies or /series when accessing from home. Now I have another problem: when switching between /movies and /series in the url I can see /series/movies or movies/series etc.. I still not fully understand how it actually works. I want them to switch. Can you help?

Comment: @Valdas The `Home` component will remain mounted while switching routes, so `Home` or `Featured` will likely need to use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `type` to run any logic when `type` value changes. An alternative might be to use a React key, i.e. `key={type}` on the component that matters to "force remount" it.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend not nesting routes inside of the index route `( when path = "/" )`. if you're going to nest a route is should be for a path like `/profile/settings` with `/settings` nested inside of `/profile`.

**this is what i change the code to:**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/movies" element={<Home type='movies'/>} />
        <Route path="/series" element={<Home type='series'/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

[More on Nested Routes](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/)